# Resampling Method

Tags: resampling

Which method  is good for resampling ASTER land surface temperature image (AST_08) with spatial resolution 90 m to the resolution of MODIS land surface temperature image (MOD11A1) which is 1000 m ?(from Nearest Neighbor resampling, Bilinear Interpolation and Cubic Convolution Interpolation methods)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is continuous data you should either use bilinear interpolation or cubic convolution. The advantages and disadvantages of each can be found here. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/resampling-method.htm